# rewrite responsive menu to css only

Tags: javascript, css, menu, responsive-design

I have menu:

### JSFIDLE

[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfa2N/1/)

---

### HTML

```
<a class="toggleMenu" href="#"><img src="img/icon-menu.png" alt=""></a>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first activeSelected"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>        
        <ul class="level1">
            <li class="first"><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Sport and relax</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
/* MENU */

.menu {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    padding: 9px 9px 6px 9px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 2px;
    color: #000;
    background: #00a1ba;
    border: 1px #00a1ba solid;
}

.menu {
    list-style: none;
    *zoom: 1;
    z-index: 99;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.menu:after {
    clear: both;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.menu a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #848484;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background: #0093aa;
}

.active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0093aa;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li {
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
}

.menu > li:hover {
    background: #0093aa;
}

.menu > li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu > li > .parent {
    /*background-image: url("../img/downArrow.png");*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.menu > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.menu > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.menu li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.menu li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #00a1ba;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 1px solid #0093aa;
}

.menu li li li a {
    background: #00a1ba;
    color: #fff;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #0093aa;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

    .menu {
        position: absolute; 
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu > li {
        float: none;
        background: #00a1ba;
        border-top: 1px solid #0093aa;
        max-width: 280px; 
        min-width: 200px;
    }

    .menu > li:hover {
        background: #0093aa;
    }

    .menu > li > a {
        color: #fff;
    }
    .menu > li > .parent {
    background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .menu li li .parent {
        /*background-image: url("../img/downArrow.png");*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .menu ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu li li a:hover {
        background: #0093aa;
    }

    .menu > li.hover > ul , .menu li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }

}
```

### JS

```
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
        }
        ;
    })

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".menu").toggle();
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 640) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".menu").hide();
        } else {
            $(".menu").show();
        }
        $(".menu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(".menu li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    }
    else if (ww >= 640) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        $(".menu").show();
        $(".menu li").removeClass("hover");
        $(".menu li a").unbind('click');
        $(".menu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}
```

### Q:

How to do **hover** and **toogle without JS** ?

Comment: Have you tried CSS `transition`?

Comment: have you tried `:active` and `:hover` ?

Comment: @HashemQolami  I do, I had some complains from another people why did I put it on jsfidle and not here, so they must click on line, I feel like in middle of two giant wind-mill stones. Give me a break! I will put it in jsfidle in 10min.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak In complex scenarios it's often useful to add a jsfiddle for testing and demo purpose **in addition to the code in the question**. Btw. http://jsfiddle.net/wfa2N/1/

Comment: @MarcelGwerder do you know how CTRL+C / CTRL+V work ? Dont be lazy :P

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak I know as you can see I posted a link, but its unecessary that every one who tries to help you creates his own fiddle. Btw. I wasn't the one asking for a jsfiddle. ;)

Comment: to everyone > JSFIDLE ADDED

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak LOL, sorry dude. I was the `lazy` one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS only example which shows you the HOVER effect you were talking about

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dMQgD/)

Hover over the Programs link and check it.
This effect can be applied to any element in your HTML

The CSS syntax is as follows

```
Element_name:Hover{
       // CSS code
}
```

Example:

```
img{
opacity:1;
}
img:hover{
opacity:0;
}
```

The above example will make an img transparent on hover.

Answer (score 0):

For multi level yu can try this one
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/gAMVM/

```
body {
background: #ccc;
font-family: helvetica, arial, serif;
font-size: 13px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: is it multi-level or just 2-level ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to do hover and toogle without JS?

There's the [`:hover` pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) which you can use in a CSS selector.

To toggle, you can just apply `display:none;` to an element or not.

What you cannot do with pure CSS is respond to `click` events. You will need JS for that.